Lemma 13, Section 5.2 of Hungerford’s Algebra

Theorem 2.2. Let $F$ be an extension field of $K$ and $f\in K[x]$. If $u\in F$ is a root of $f$ and $\sigma \in \text{Aut}_K F$, then $\sigma (u)\in F$ is also a root of $f$.


If $F$ is an extension field of $K$ and $E$ is an intermediate field of the extension such that $E$ is algebraic and Galois over $K$, then $E$ is stable (relative to $F$ and $K$).
Proof: If $u\in E$, let $f\in K[x]$ be the irreducible polynomial of $u$ and let $u = u_1,u_2,…,u_r$ be the distinct roots of $f$ that lie in $E$. Then $r\leq n = \text{deg}f$. If $\tau \in \text{Aut}_K E$, then it follows from Theorem 2.2 that $\tau$ simply permutes the $u_i$. This implies that the coefficients of the monic polynomial $g(x) = (x - u_1) (x - u_2)\cdots (x - u_r) \in E[x]$ are fixed by every $\tau\in \text{Aut}_KE$. Since $E$ is Galois over $K$, we must have $g\in K[x]$. Now $u = u_1$ is a root of $g$ and hence $f\mid g$. Since $g$ is monic and $\text{deg} g\leq \text{deg} f$, we must have $f = g$. Consequently, all the roots of $f$ are distinct and lie in $E$. Now if $u \in \text{Aut}_KF$, then $\sigma(u)$ is a root of $f$ by Theorem 2.2, whence $\sigma (u) \in E$. Therefore, $E$ is stable relative to $F$ and $K$.

I am kind of feeling lost with this proof. I don’t understand most of the sentences. Questions: What does “$\tau$ permutes the $u_i$” mean? I think coefficient of polynomial $g$ is product of $u_i$, let say $u_{k_1}\cdots u_{k_s}$. How $\tau (u_{k_1}\cdots u_{k_s})= u_{k_1}\cdots u_{k_s}$?
I known, $E$ is Galois over $K$ $\iff$ for any $v\in E - K$, there exists a $K$-automorphism $\tau\in \text{Aut}_KE$ such that $\tau (v)\neq v$. From this definition, coefficient of $g$ must be in $K$, since coefficient of $g$ is fixed by every $\tau \in \text{Aut}_KE$.

Edit: I am adding comments of Professor Arturo Magidin. “$\tau$ permutes the factors of $g$, so it leaves $g$ invariant. Any ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ induces a ring homomorphism $R[x]\to S[x]$ that sends $a_nx^n+\cdots + a_1x+a_0$ to $f(a_n)x_n+\cdots +f(a_1)x+f(a_0)$.” For reference last sentence is exercise 1 section 3.5 in Hungerford’s Algebra.

By Thm 2.2, $\tau(u_i)=u_j$. So we can just think of $\tau$ as an element of the symmetric group $S_r$ defined by $i\mapsto j$. The coefficients of $g$ are the elementary symmetric functions, so are invariant under $\tau$.

@beeclu I don’t know if I am correct, notion of symmetric function is in appendix (title of appendix is symmetric rational function). Which comes after lemma 13 section 5.2.

Elementary symmetric functions are just coefficients of $(x-u_1)(x-u_2)\cdots(x-u_n)$. For example $n=3$ gives $u_1+u_2+u_3$, $u_1u_2+u_1u_3+u_2u_3$, and $u_1u_2u_3$ as coefficients. So not exactly the case that every coefficient is strictly a product. "Symmetric" in the sense that you can permute indices 1,2,3 and they don't change.

@beeclu yaa I was wrong about my assumption of coefficient of $g$. Still I don’t see easily why $\tau$ fixes coefficient of $g$.

$\tau$ permutes the factors of $g$, so it leaves $g$ invariant.

@ArturoMagidin I thought about that same reasoning but I didn’t feel satisfactory because $x$ is an indeterminate. I guess if we replace $x$ with $1_E$ then things becomes more concrete.

Any ring homomorphism $f\colon R\to S$ induces a ring homomorphism $R[x]\to S[x]$ that sends $a_nx^n+\cdots + a_1x+a_0$ to $f(a_n)x^n + \cdots + f(a_1)x+f(a_0)$. This is covered by Hungerford well before this section. You do not "replace $x$" with anything.  You apply $\tau$ to the polynomial.
